# java.net.ProtocolException : Unexpected Status line

Tags: java, android, exception, httpurlconnection

I have written a code for reading two JSON files from uhunt.onlinejudge.org. When the first file is read, which is read perfectly, then if I try to read the second file, it throws a `java.net.protocolException: Unexpected Status Line`;

My uHunt class:

```
public class uHunt  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void ,Void> {
    private String userName;
    private String uID;

    public uHunt(String _uName){
        userName = _uName;
    }

    public uHunt(){}

    private void getUID(){
        String tempURL = "https://uhunt.onlinejudge.org/api/uname2uid/" + userName;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(tempURL);
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            //urlc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0a2) Gecko/20110613 Firefox/6.0a2");
            InputStream is = urlc.getInputStream();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
            String result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
            uID = result;
            urlc.disconnect();
            is.close();
            urlc = null;
            is = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void ...urls){
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try{
            getUID();
            //uID = "803880";
            URL url = new URL("https://uhunt.onlinejudge.org/api/subs-user/" + uID);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }
            line = sb.toString();
            connection.disconnect();
            is.close();
            sb.delete(0,sb.length());
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(line);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.d("Exception","Exception thrown");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:54)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:186)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:127)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:737)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:609)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:471)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:244)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source:0)
at com.example.redwanul.cptracker.uHunt.doInBackground(uHunt.java:69)
at com.example.redwanul.cptracker.uHunt.doInBackground(uHunt.java:23)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

So next, I deleted the function call getUID() from the function doInBackground(), and stored the uID manually for checking purpose, this time the code ran without any exceptions. It seemed like that the HttpURLConnector and/or InputStream is not closing properly from the call of getUID() method. But in order to get the user id first, I need to call getUID() first.

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I haven't. Are you parsing from uHunt as well?

Comment: No, i am parsing from a simple API. But i only get this error on android 5.0
Not sure why.